# What is Difference Between Price, Special Price and Final Price in Magento?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2.3

In magento 1 and 2,

There's  **price** , **special_price** and **final_price** and I can't find the difference between them.

Answer (score 4):

- Price in the sense of the cost of the product.
- Special Price. To offer a Special Price, enter a discounted price and complete the date range fields to establish when the promotion goes into effect. On both the catalog list and product pages, the regular price is crossed out, and the Special Price appears in bold red.
- And Final price is a discounted price or special price.

Comment: if we don't add special price than price is to be a final price?

Comment: not all the time. if you have catalog discount rules then final price will be calculated from price and the discount rules that apply to the product.